# getting unspecified error in docusign API while using COMPOSITE template

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Hi I am trying to use COMPOSITE template to club one template and add a document while creating envelope.

The complete request is below.

However i am getting "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR" as below

I am new to use docusign and composite template API.

It would be great if someone can point me the error as i tried the request after referring to online material about composite templates.

Thanks for reading!!!

RESPONSE:

```
{
errorCode: "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR"
message: "An item with the same key has already been added."
}
```

REQUEST

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACTID/envelopes HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6640
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>username.com</Username><Password>PA$$W0RD</Password><IntegratorKey>INTG KEY</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data
{
    "accountId": "act_ID",
    "brandId": "brnd_ID",
    "status": "SENT",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "templateId": "temp_ID_1"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "name": "Signer Name",
                                "email": "signer@email.com",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "signer",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "SignerRole",
                                            "value": "signerRole"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "SignerAddress",
                                            "value": "test TT DEMO"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "date",
                                            "value": "05/10/2014"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "carbonCopies": [
                            {
                                "name": "CarbonCopyName",
                                "email": "carboncopy@emailcom",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "carbonCopyRole"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": 2,
                    "document": {
                        "name": "body.pdf"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="body.pdf"
%PDF-1.4
%????
2 0 obj
<<
--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

Comment: Why are you using a data field (textTab) for a date?  Why not use the pre-defined `date` or `dateSigned` tabs?

Comment: I just used some text fields but my primary objective to see if i can combine two template and introduce a document in the middle. Yes i will  use "date" for passing dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each individual **compositeTemplate** object in the request must specify both:

- document(s) -- either defined via **serverTemplate**(s) or via standalone
  **document** that's specified as part of the request

AND

- recipients

For example, the following multipart request will create an Envelope that contains the documents from the server Template, followed by the additional document that's specified in the request:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/201105/envelopes HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"username@test.com","Password":"mypassword","IntegratorKey":"ABCD-dbd5f342-d9f6-47c3-b293-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 272956
Expect: 100-continue


--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "status" : "sent",
    "emailSubject" : "Test Envelope Subject",
    "emailBlurb" : "Test Envelope Blurb",
    "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 2,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "abbysemail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Abby Abbott",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Initiator",
                    "routingOrder":"1"
                }
                ]
            }
        }]
    },
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "abbysemail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Abby Abbott",
                    "recipientId": "1"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": 1,
            "name": "Customer Agreement",
            "fileExtension": "pdf"
        }
    }
]}
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="CustomerAgreement.pdf"; documentid="1"

PDF_BYTE_STREAM_HERE
--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

If I wanted the additional document to appear first in the envelope, I would simply swap the order of **compositeTemplate** objects in the request, so that the document is specified before the server template:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/201105/envelopes HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"username@test.com","Password":"mypassword","IntegratorKey":"ABCD-dbd5f342-d9f6-47c3-b293-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 272956
Expect: 100-continue


--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "status" : "sent",
    "emailSubject" : "Test Envelope Subject",
    "emailBlurb" : "Test Envelope Blurb",
    "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "abbysemail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Abby Abbott",
                    "recipientId": "1"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": 1,
            "name": "Customer Agreement",
            "fileExtension": "pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "templateId": "TEMPLATE_ID"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 2,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "abbysemail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Abby Abbott",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Initiator",
                    "routingOrder":"1"
                }
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
]}
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="CustomerAgreement.pdf"; documentid="1"

PDF_BYTE_STREAM_HERE
--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

Based on the code you've posted in your question, I'd suspect that the error is being caused by the fact that the second **compositeTemplate** object in the request does not specify recipients.

Finally, a few additional comments:

- Make sure that the recipient info (email, name, recipientId) you specify matches exactly across all composite template objects.
- If you use a multipart request to create the envelope (as shown in the above examples), pay close attention to line breaks -- they must occur exactly as shown in the examples.
- Although you *can* use a multipart request to create an envelope that contains document(s) you specify as part of the request (as the examples above show), an easier/simpler way to do so would be to use a "normal" (i.e., not multi-part) request whereby you simply specify ***base-64-encoded*** document bytes within the **document** object itself, by using the **documentBase64** property -- which eliminates the need for the multipart request.  See https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Document Parameters.htm?Highlight=documentbase64.

Comment: Wonderful. I saw my mistakes with the "line breaks" i even tried passing the recipients still getting unspecified error. Thank you for providing along with sample structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this is related to the inline document you're supplying.  I see that you specify the document name but no `documentId` and that might be causing the error as it probably defaults to `documentId` = `1`, which is most likely in use by the server template document.

Try something like this:

```
"document": {
    "name": "body.pdf",
    "documentId": "2"
}
```

Comment: I tried specifying the id, still same error. Can you atleast comment if I am passing the structure correctly? (including document ID)